# How to find $x$ on this exponential function

Tags: functions

I'm not in math, but I really want to know how to solve this:

$$(1.08^{x}) = 100/55$$

I'm not able to factor $100/55$ to get the result.

Can anybody tell me what the easiest way to get the value of $x$ is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extracting logarithms.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli. Are you able to show me an example?

Comment: $x = \log_{108}(100/55) = \frac{\ln(108/55)}{\ln(108)}$

Comment: If $a,c>0$, $$a^x=c\iff x\ln a=\ln c$$

Comment: Thank you very much, @G.Sassatelli. Please, post it as an answer, so I can approve and rate it.

Comment: @Jaumzera Zain Patel's answer covers that.

Comment: In Mathematica it would look like Log[100/55,108].

Comment: @StevenGregory Just curiousity : Is there a free light version of Mathematica ?

Comment: I guess WolframAlpha satisfies that, sort of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1.08^x = e^{x \ln 1.08} = \frac{100}{55} \iff x \ln 1.08 = \ln \frac{100}{55} \iff x = \frac{\ln 100/55}{\ln 27/25}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, @Zain Patel

Comment: @Jaumzera it does not matter whether you use the ln-function or the log-function, but do not mix them! In short $log_a(b)=\frac{ln(b)}{ln(a)}=\frac{log(b)}{log(a)}$, but $\frac{log(b)}{ln(a)}$ or $\frac{ln(b)}{log(a)}$ would be wrong.

Comment: With "$log$" I mean $log_{10}$, the decadical logarithm.

Comment: @Peter \log and \ln produces $\log$ and $\ln$.

Comment: Sorry, but, where did ln 27/25 come from? I'm still trying to understand.

Comment: What's $1.08$ in fraction form?

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about logarithm ? If not, simply press the "ln" key on your calculator and it will work :
$$
1.08^x = 100/55 \\
(\frac{108}{100})^x = \frac{100}{55} \\
(\frac{27}{25})^x = \frac{20}{11} \\
ln \left((\frac{27}{25})^x \right) = ln \left( \frac{20}{11} \right) \\
x\ ln(\frac{27}{25}) =ln \left( \frac{20}{11} \right) \\
x = \frac{ln \left( \frac{20}{11} \right)}{ ln(\frac{27}{25})}
$$